# Сохранять index текущей страницы

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Как можно во фрагменте сохранять его index?

Так как у меня во фрагменте *меняются* страницы мне нужно сохранять этот index, чтоб при желании я мог обратиться к конкретной странице.

Comment: Во фрагменте ViewPager находится?

Comment: @ValeryPonomarenko да, нашёл даже вариант что то типо ViewPager.getCurrentItem() но если честно не знаю куда его правильно тыкнуть.

Comment: Опишите задачу подробнее. Что именно вы хотите в итоге и в чём заключается проблема. Желательно с примерами кода.

Comment: @Inkognito можно добавить OnPageChangeListener ко ViewPager и при изменении страницы сохранять ее индекс/позицию

Answer (score 0):

Все просто:

Создаете статическую переменную:

```
private static final String SavingViewPagerPosition = "saving_position";
```

Реализовываете `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit = mPreferences.edit();
```

Затем, например в методе `onStop` получаете текущую позицию вашего `ViewPager` и сохраняете её:

```
mEdit.putInt(SavingViewPagerPosition, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
mEdit.apply();
```

А затем, в методе `onCreate` или `onResume` получаете сохраненную позицию, и передаете ее в ваш `ViewPager` в метод `setCurrentItem`:

```
int endPosition = mPreferences.getInt(SavingViewPagerPosition, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(endPosition);
```

Таким образом вы можете сохранять где пожелаете, и загружать где пожелаете.